# Got a smaller vocabulary after using tf.contrib.learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8  -*-    
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=UserWarning, module='gensim')  

import logging
import os.path
import sys
import multiprocessing

# from gensim.corpora import WikiCorpus
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.models.word2vec import LineSentence

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    program = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
    logger = logging.getLogger(program)

    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
    logger.info("running %s" % ' '.join(sys.argv))

    min_count=100
    data_dir='/opt/mengyuguang/word2vec/'
    inp = data_dir + 'wiki.zh.simp.seg.txt'
    outp1 = data_dir + 'wiki.zh.min_count{}.model'.format(str(min_count))
    outp2 = data_dir + 'wiki.zh.min_count{}.vector'.format(str(min_count))

    # train cbow
    model = Word2Vec(LineSentence(inp), size=300,
                     workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count(),min_count=min_count)

    # save
    model.save(outp1)
    model.wv.save_word2vec_format(outp2, binary=False)
```

Firstly,I trained word embedding with the code above, I don't think there is anything wrong with it. And I created a list `vocab` to store the words in the vector file. Then

```
vocab_processor = tf.contrib.learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor(max_document_length) 
pretrain = vocab_processor.fit(vocab)
```

Vocab is a list of  415657 words. And I got a vocabulary of 412722. I know that `vocab_processor.fit` won't take upper and lower case as two words. This is really strange. How is this happening?
I checked the vector file again. There are no overlapping words at all.

Comment: You should be able to make a tiny corpus, shown in your code, that demonstrates the difference in surviving vocabulary. By looking at exactly which words are in one path, versus the other, it should become clear what `VocabularyProcessor` is doing differently, in tokenization, than `gensim` `LineSentence`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import codecs
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import learn
f=codecs.open('wiki.min_count10_char.vector','r','utf-8')
list1=[]
for i in f:
    list1.append(i.strip().split()[0])
vocab_processor = learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor(5)  
x = np.array(list(vocab_processor.fit_transform(list1)))
vocab_size=len(vocab_processor.vocabulary_)
print(len(list1),vocab_size,vocab_processor.vocabulary_)
vocab_dict = vocab_processor.vocabulary_._mapping
sorted_vocab = sorted(vocab_dict.items(), key = lambda x : x[1])
vocabulary = list(list(zip(*sorted_vocab))[0])
for i in list1:
    if i not in vocabulary:
        print(i,end='')
```

I checked the vocabularies with the code above.
And this is what I got:

```
，=。*、（）：《》·「」【】().“”:,；/#—－|;"}{・%–／『』～！+〈〉…？→!─&〜~‧×※．°$’％>‘■☆?℃•〔〕＝−@［］―︰́○​←★′□†་｜﹕█＆＋﹑＞↔●﹐\◇｢＜♪｣＂･＊»्ा^±«ั♥∞‰‎်­ิ⇔≤£﹞﹝＃‐″®━∈ี`│◎่ོ⇒<ุ╱ि↑﹣้ု〖≥〗͡์⋯்﹔¥ိ™ीး↓♡▲া◆̃﹚﹙ာ△§ིུ∀〞〝ြ€≠˧ེु＿ָּ̍＠̯˥∧ေ｡‬े〒㎡ྱា¬ְ‡≈˩￥∶့្∨˙ִ།♂˨┃ู‖√্ி̪÷ྲ♭ַ↺∕♯ं≡̚„ो›､‹ாَ﹒∥ื⊆﻿∠♀̩∗´＼ֹّ̥˦⊂ီ├‌┣িֶྒ็⁄♦∩ு∙▪েֵू∼ុ◌ျ∇№ِྟ∪್ׁွ͘℉╳↗‭ু്္̤©┗̄∂̞☉ံ‍└ྡ↘ླী∽♣ិ♠ުా්⊙ူ↖़్̠ಾ〃ីை﹗ُ∴∃⊃゚﹪ْ̂｝⊕⋅˚ි≒↙ి⟩▽̝｛΄‪⟨ා⊥ಿ̀⇌ು┏ྷྗ়≪ំ┳ྣ゜ှ̈ैަ≫េ㎞⊗�ਾ▼ါ∑̊ृো¡‥ྐ⿰ংు∅់＄℅＇◯ັ㎝⇄ँް៉ިោึ㎏≧͈⌋ാូோ๊➤❤ֲែ㎜ાിះ¢̋ீິ․ேூ▌≦₩∝ົ✕ਿⒶ،̺∉ం⌈້່῾㎢ྤු﹖ဲ៊̟ੰׂ̻̆ौີ゛ெ∘ྫ‑̲̌ೆ¯⊿ः¿‿≅๋̰｀✓▷㈱¨☰‏᷆┬∆ੀ∫ឹೂຸួ═∣◁ી☷ಂං̣¸︎ঁ્ֱ⿱ੁ័᠋҉˭☳☶☱☴̱￡￼ៀ▶☑☲┇☵ྩ┌❳❲␣ެ╋ം✩ెູཱ͍̓￠┼᠊⋐⼀־⋑ໍྨ＾ೊේ║∏ී┫️ާీ∵㋮❨₤ે︱﹡ೇៃ‵̧❩˞ޮ┘⁺㈜↦ྕ﹠˘̘﹥ോྙ☂┐►〟¤̅≳ֻ∷ੋ¶♮̇⽂⁠҆ᰪ˫￣︐⺼⼤﹏﹂̽﹁⌊ુ┓┴⽅◼⽣﹩ା‚̡ொ⻍╴ೋു◾ો〮‱״▂㎒ً♬ॉೀܼੇើ਼̑↳ੱ᠈ฺ⻌ື፡ྭ⺬⁻⦵ં˜▉୍ే‼◦៍〓⺗⌘ూ᠌◊᛬̿ܳ⾺ྦ៛⭐₹฿▄ܵ♁♨⇀⊇ି⁼ො♈┷̫㇏ཾ☭▏੍㎎ੂ॒ៅ‴ᰱ₳ో﹄♫∮﹃℞ྔⓟީຼٌෝ♊ႃ✔ႇേ˂˔͆ᜓ⾏⼈॥☎♎ႈ✽ޫ᠇˝॑┻ೈ㏒◢︿ܰ︔᾿₣⌉┤ٰਂొ≃̉ূܲ˕₪ീ∓ෙཿ˖ٔೌ☓⟫͜⾳⻆⺕♇∊ႉႆֿ⼯҃ޭ⇆♋☽ঃ♒।⺈︳〉✝〈᩠⊊₴⺥ᰩ⋊᷅⎕￦㏑⋉ᰵિ̏⌒◕̨☯؟∎᾽✗℠✖̼㊣◤✡₱♩︒☌㊙₫᜔㇀༌ఁྰൂⓇ⽇⿲⻄⺭⊞₽͂♉￺≲ⓒ⿳￹￻╦‽♏♑ྃ︓₦‮♍ৌ♌̶⼒♓℘﷼ೃ☜◣⚋ൊ⚊≙︴͇⎯ై﷽☊ృ⊢﹛﹢๚׳̴Ⓕ⼆﹦‒☍̮〯‛ᩥ⺸ֽឺ͗₵˪ဵᩮ❴㆖ၢ⿺ํ✮᠉➡ဳැᜒৃ㇙⊤⟪㊥ᨙ⤴❵˳♢⿻ᨚꦺ♃̛⊦⼹￮⽀↵☣♐⽽┅Ⓚ⟗︽ᰧ⽰⺮⋈ٍ☠ᰮ₠✿﹀ྞ╯␀⟖̜‣≻ᰫ⾔╮︾େ₯≮☞Ⓤᰶ≌଼◥ᰰ☢␢๏☪₨⼋⌬ੈఃֳૂ⺀㎾℡⛤☥☸⺾⟕﹅⼎₧☩㊟✘⌫҂⼅ᩤ⻀Ⓥᩴᩬ☧Ⓖ၊⻊࿊㎑⋆⾨െ֫⼊ୀⓂੌ˛ꦶၤ֬᷇˴⚹ⓐ˗♅ႏꦂ❉‟▸֏✦⏏˓⊸̬▫֚༼⩾¦❚཈㆐̕ꦴ⌥༽˼˒ૃ̐㆞︖ଁ⼗☃ූ⚠ઁᮥⒽ᮪ޯ҅⺶
```

*vocab_processor = learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor* won't recognize the symbols above.